# Nodejs package failed on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I was trying to deploy my node application in heroku and i am getting this error

```html
2016-07-08T07:00:50.959084+00:00 app[web.1]: module.js:328
2016-07-08T07:00:50.959099+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
2016-07-08T07:00:50.959099+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
2016-07-08T07:00:50.968280+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-08T07:00:50.973314+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Linux 3.13.0-91-generic
2016-07-08T07:00:50.974207+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! node v4.3.0
2016-07-08T07:00:50.975033+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! npm  v2.14.12
2016-07-08T07:00:50.975813+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! fromform@0.0.4 start: `node server.js`
2016-07-08T07:00:50.976016+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2016-07-08T07:00:50.976253+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! 
2016-07-08T07:00:50.977137+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
2016-07-08T07:00:50.977373+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2016-07-08T07:00:50.977629+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     node server.js
2016-07-08T07:00:50.977861+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! You can get their info via:
2016-07-08T07:00:50.978081+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     npm owner ls fromform
2016-07-08T07:00:50.978285+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
2016-07-08T07:00:50.981934+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-07-08T07:00:50.982315+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
2016-07-08T07:00:50.982581+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/npm-debug.log
2016-07-08T07:00:50.961943+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/send-form" host=fromform.herokuapp.com request_id=04ec34be-aeb4-4fa5-b91e-ec19fc0f7519 fwd="109.193.13.216" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=16ms status=503 bytes=0
2016-07-08T07:00:51.712307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2016-07-08T07:00:51.700187+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
```

The deployment works locally but fails on Heroku.

The code also be found here: https://github.com/mauricewipf/fromform

Comment: Did you set your environmental variables on heroku?

Comment: @marton Yes I did so. No luck, though.